# Postgresql between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, valentina-studio

i am learning SQL at the moment and i was wondering if somebody could help me.
I´m working with postgresql and my task ist to write a query which shows all the, in this case, employees having their 25th anniversary, lets say tomorrow or in a week.

Using an interval function shows everyone between my two dates.
How do i write a query giving information about employees having their 25th anniversary according to the "current_date"?

Would be nice if someone could help me!!

Comment: Use equality predicate on date of birth, subtracting 1 year from desired date: select current_date - interval '1 year'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be that they started 25 years ago, with a week of leeway, so you can filter like this:

```
where start_date >= curdate() - interval '25 year' and
      start_date < curdate() + interval '1 week' - interval 25 year'
```